# Basic question on how to redirect users to third party payment sites

Tags: web-development, redirect

My sincere apologies, if this question is too vague but I am really curious in understanding how payment redirection works in web development without exposing data in url parameters.

In detail with example:

1. I go to Jet blue website(jetblue.com), search for flight, choose flight, fill all the necessary information and select paypal as the payment option and click next.
2. Browser redirects me to paypal website(paypal.com) and on the paypal website, it shows the correct amount from Jet Blue.
3. I had chrome developer network tab opened and I don't see any POST requests to Paypal also nothing on the URL parameters relating to amount.

How is this done usually in Web development?

Comment: I would appreciate at least a comment mentioning what is wrong with this question before downvoting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways.

The two most common are, data out of band, and data in band.

For "data in band" you would send the proposed information (like amount) at the time of the paypal button creation. I won't go too far into the process, but essentially you send the transaction information, then get back a token. That token is then passed at the time of the actual redirection. The servers code is responsible for tracking the PayPal token against the actual transaction.

For "out of band" method, you would essentially create a static button. This works great for payments that don't vary in price.  There is no need to get a token because you made the button years or months in advance.

You can see more info at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create_payment_button/

In both cases, PayPal will  send a notification back to the site, or it's administrators, when the transaction completes.

There are tons of ways this can work,  and many different ways to accomplish all the steps, but that is the basics.